# Showing $aS=S=Sa$ for all $a\in S$ using a specific definition of a group $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

*NB: This part of Exercise 1.9.2 of "Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory," by John Howie. There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699723/show-that-s-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-as-s-sa) but it doesn't ask for the specific definition below.*

### The Definition:

> **Definition:** A semigroup $S$ is a *group* if there exists an $e$ in $S$ such that for all $a$ in $S$, $ea=a$ and for all $x$ in $S$ there exists an $y$ in $S$ such that $yx=e$.

### The Problem:

> Let $S$ be a semigroup. Show that $S$ is a group (as defined above) if and only if for all $a$ in $S$, $aS=S=Sa$.

### Thoughts:

Fix $a\in S$. It is enough to show that both $\lambda_a: S\to S$, given by $s\mapsto as$, and $\rho_a: S\to S$, given by $s\mapsto sa$, are bijections.

### Subproblem:

> How do I show that $xe=x$ for any $x$ in $S$ given the definition above?

### My Attempt:

I'm stumped.

Comment: See Proposition 1.8 of Cain's *"Nine Chapters on the Semigroup Art"*

Comment: This question should be closed, as this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699765) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699723/show-that-s-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-as-s-sa?rq=1) answers your question.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin But that question doesn't use the required definition.

Comment: Look at my EDIT and then please close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $aS = S = Sa$ for all $a \in S$, all elements of $S$ are both $\mathcal{R}$- and $\mathcal{L}$-equivalent. It follows that $S$ consists of a single $\mathcal{H}$-class. This $\mathcal{H}$-class contains the product of (any) two of its elements and hence it is a group by Theorem 2.2.5 of Howie's book.

EDIT. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699765) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699723/show-that-s-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-as-s-sa?rq=1) answers your question. Indeed, it is shown in this answer that there exists a right identity in $S$. Of course a dual proof would show the existence of a left identity $e$. Now, since for all $x \in S$, $e \in xS$, there exists $y$ such that $yx = e$.

Comment: Thank you. Whilst this answers the question, I'm looking for something a little more elementary than this proof. (I'm reading Howie's book and I don't want any anachronisms, citing later theorems for earlier exercises.)

Comment: I might be able to understand this better once I've read the relevant section.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 2.2.5 of Howie's book makes use of (1.1.7) of the book, which states that *"a non-empty subset $T$ of $S$ is a subgroup of $S$ if and only if $(\forall a\in T) aT=T$ and $Ta=T$"*, which uses the result we're trying to prove.

Comment: For completeness, here is Theorem 2.2.5: *"If $H$ is an $\mathcal{H}$-class in a semigroup $S$ then either $H^2\cap H=\emptyset$ or $H^2=H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $S$."*